# How do you add unsigned numbers in VHDL within one clock cycle?

Tags: vhdl

Here is the code snippet:

```
signal number1                    : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal number2                    : unsigned(9 downto 0);
signal result                     : unsigned(19 downto 0);

result <= b"00_0000_0000" & (number1 + number2);
```

There is an overflow problem when the result is 11 bits.

I want to do the addition within one clock cycle, which means that addition has to be solved within only one line of code.

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Try adding 11 bit signals. (What's it about *clock cycle*s?)

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean adding 11 bit signal? Can you give me more hints?


 "What's it about clock cycles?" One line of code to solve this addition

Comment: You presented how to get a 20-bit result from a 10-bit sum. Try extending *input* signals.

Comment: @greybeard Extending nunber1 and number2 are impossible. Cause I use them also for another use.

Comment: "I want to do the addition within one clock cycle , which means that addition has to be solved within only one line of code."  Lines of code are not related to any number of clock cycles.

Comment: @asdfex Yes, I  know. I want to make it simpler to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try

```vhdl
result <= b"0000_0000_0" & ((b"0" & number1) + (b"0" & number2));
```